# centos 5.6, virtual on Vsphere

Tags: networking, ip, centos5, vmware-vsphere, mtu

suddenly my virtual centos server (5.6 on VMWare-VSphere) is not working...
It started with the url not responding, nor the ip. (NO HTTP response, no ping).
When I entered on the server via ssh to start troubleshooting I noticed that most of commands don't work anymore:

- top-> session hangs (it's not slow anyway)
- ps -> session hangs (funny enough apache server and web app are running and sending me emails)
- on some directory ls -l -> machine hangs after first line, if ls > l.txt the file show only the first line
- "more" command, also hangs on some file.

So there are very little things I can try.
I recovered my virtual machine from yesterday and before yesterday, and they show the same behaviour, it hangs on commands (but yesterday they were working).
There is no firewall on the machine, there is on the host though.
I can connect with ftp but I can't download files nor list directory apart the user top directory...

Working hard right now, any idea appreciated

Comment: update: a colleague can surf and use the machine perfectly, it seems that it's a network problem with the provider...not fixed yet, but incredibly weird

Comment: so it's possible that the previously mentioned commands don't hang the machine, is the answer (like the ls output) that doesn't get through the ssh connection and it's the terminal that "hangs".
Now the virtual host provider blames the network connection provider...hmmmm

Comment: It is unlikly your machine is hung, you just have severe packet loss caused by the host sending packets too large for your network connection

Comment: yes, of course, when I understood that it was the ssh session that was hanging and not the processes or the machine, I started to solve the problem...panic doesn't help to think clearly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very very long shot here. Make sure your mtu is set correctly across your network. If you are using a VPN it can be 1490 instead of 1500. Run ping to do this: http://gregalbrecht.com/2008/06/10/detecting-mtu/

If it is below 1500 you will have to change settings on your client an host to limit. I won't go into details on how to do this right now as it may not be the problem. Let me know if it is though

Comment: It's a very good shot indeed! I hade the same idea yesterday night and I changed mtu on my PC and started working.
Afterward I found out that the netowrk provider changed some router settings and that the hosting provider failed to update something...
Good one!

Comment: HAHAHA that made my day, actually got asked it in an interview a while back. Glad you got it working